# Pentaho kettle denormalizer or concat

Tags: kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have one step that I need to concat x rows into one separated by coma or similar. I have this data on my final step:

[image]

I need to have the "tarifas" row in the same column with the 5 diferent "tarifas" for the same "REFERENCIA" : example:

tarifas:

T00:6.9000,T01:7.9000,T02:8.9000,T03:9.9000,T04:10.9000,T05:11.9000

I saw denormalizer step but can't get a good result.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the **Group By** step?

It has an operation called **Concatenate string separated by ,** which is exactly what you want here. For your other non-group fields use **First non-null value** as the operation.

Make sure your data is sorted on the group field and then the tarifas field.

Comment: That worked perfectly but for some reason I get the new row with some duplicates for example: T00:19.9000, T00:19.9000, T00:19.9000, T01:20.9000, T02:21.9000, T03:22.9000, T04:23.9000, T05:24.9000

Comment: If you preview the data coming from the step just before the Group By, are there duplicate rows, is the stream correctly sorted on the group by field (b2btad_REFERENCIA) and the tarifas field?

Comment: You must sort rows before grouping by the same columns.